# How to know file name for File not found in VBscript

Tags: vbscript, error-handling

I am new to vbcript. I am using the following code to copy various files from different locations to one folder:

Code:

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("D:\Copy Support\LocationPath.txt", 1)
totalfile = 0
Const OverwriteExisting = True

Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
    strCharacters  = objFile.ReadLine
    VFileName =  strCharacters

   Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   objFSO.CopyFile VFileName , "D:\Variance Reports\", OverwriteExisting    

    totalfile = totalfile + 1
Loop

Wscript.Echo "Total Files  " & totalfile
```

The txt file i am using contains addresses for different files but when the file is missing or renamed this script gives an error during copying. Can anyone please help me to create a message which file is missing or renamed.

Answer (score 3):

Use objFSO.FileExists(VFileName) to test whether the source file exists and WScript.Echo or MsgBox to log the facts.

BTW, you need exactly one FSO.